# How to convert custom detection pytorch model YoloV5 for OpenCv?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, pytorch, onnx

I am trying to convert custom YoloV5s pytorch model to use it with OpenCv using ONNX, unfortunately there are some errors. I would appreciate if someone could help me

```
import torch
import onnx
from onnxsim import simplify


# Step 1: Load the YOLOv5 model
model = torch.hub.load('https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5','custom',
                       'best.pt')
batch_size = 16
# Step 2: Export the model to ONNX format
torch.onnx.export(model,
                  torch.zeros(batch_size, 3, 640, 640),
                  "yolov5s.onnx",
                  opset_version=11)

# Step 3: Simplify the exported ONNX model
onnx_model = onnx.load("yolov5s.onnx")
simplified_model, _ = simplify(onnx_model)
onnx.save(simplified_model, "yolov5s.onnx")
```

Comment: model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5','custom','best.pt') 

Dosen't work either

Comment: all you've shown is the pytorch side. does that fail or does it succeed? can you use the exported onnx model with pytorch?